# Routing Cakephp with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, cakephp, routes

Below is the html and cakephp code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        // configure the routes
        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            // route for the home page
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            // route for the about page
            templateUrl: 'about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
        .when('/contact/', {
            // route for the contact page
            templateUrl: 'contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            // when all else fails
            templateUrl: 'routeNotFound.html',
            controller: 'notFoundController'
         });
      });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="homeController">
    <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
    <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Below codes are on default.ctp  using cakephp3

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on #about   url "http://localhost/finalcake3/pages/about"
Clicking on #contact url "http://localhost/finalcake3/pages/contact-us"

But adding the script below will not work using angular js in cakephp.

```
 <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        // configure the routes
        $routeProvider
        .when('/about', {
            // route for the about us page
            templateUrl: 'http://localhost/finalcake3/pages/about',
            controller: 'AboutCNTRL'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            // route for the contact us page
            templateUrl: 'http://localhost/finalcake3/pages/contact-us',
            controller: 'ContactCNTRL'
        })
      });
    </script>
```

I want my existing cakephp website to use angular js. Is there any codes to include I need in-order this to function.

Comment: The question is too broad as there are multiple way to do what you want. You need to be more specific. Why are you using hashtag for links, what are the routes for cakephp and what do you want your cake controllers to handle?

Comment: Because that was Angular JS be like using hash tag    "#id" .

Comment: What *exactly* is not working and how *should* it work? Read http://university.utest.com/writing-quality-bug-reports-and-utest-etiquette/ This question is more like "Have some code, go figure what my problem with it is."

Answer (score 1):

first question ?  why do you use AngularJs like this ? You can do an APIrest with CakePhp and retrieve easily Json Datas with Angular when you call the url of your cakephp project which return Json data. Better to use Angular like this.

Then, you have just to create your html template with your {{datas}}  and call the json datas via your cakephp urls.

- API rest CakePhp2
  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/development/rest.html
- API rest CakePhp3
  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/fr/development/rest.html

Comment: I would like my website to load once only, so that when i go to another page it will not load or refresh my browser. Does api rest in cakephp3 also do the same with what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

templateURL: is expecting a path to your template partial files in the directory. Try changing the path to whatever the relative path should be. A url with "/" prefix is relative to the domain, without the "/" prefix it will be relative to your base url. The absolute paths you are pointing to are resolved via CakePHP so Angular doesn't know what to to with those paths as they don't point directly to a partial template file.

so...

templateUrl: '/finalcake3/pages/about.html',

or

templateUrl: 'finalcake3/pages/about.html',